# Proving the multiplicity of eigenvalues of the Laplacian on a disk?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, harmonic-functions

An eigenvalue $\lambda_{nk}$ for the Laplacian on a unit disk is given by the $k$-th zero of the Bessel function of order $n$.

When $n = 0$ we have simple eigenvalues. But when $n \ge 1$ there are two corresponding eigenfunctions.

My question is, how can this be proven?